# executing drush site install in c#

Tags: c#, windows, drupal-7, windows-server-2008, drush

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Drush Site-Install in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14366489/using-drush-site-install-in-c-sharp)

I'm trying to do a Drupal site install using Drush in C# as part of a full Windows Server site installation using MSI.
The Drush Commmand I am using is

```
C:\ProgramData\Drush\Drush.bat -y si application_name --db-url=sqlsrv://admin_name:password(local)\SQLEXPRESS:/database_name --account-name=admin --account-mail=name@test.com --account-pass=Password1234 --site-mail="admin@company.com" --site-name="Site Name" install_configure_form.site_default_country=GB install_configure_form.date_default_timezone="Europe/London"
```

And this works perfectly when run from cmd.exe when in the working directory (inetpub\application_name)

The issue arises when the above is put into code and executed during an installation and always results in the following error (with a different file name each time)

*Unable to decompress C:\ProgramData\Drush\lib\druFD63.tmp.gz*

The c# code being used to execute the command is as follows:

```
public static ActionResult Drush_Configuration(Session session)
    {       
        string strArgs = "C:\ProgramData\Drush\Drush.bat -y si application_name --db-url=sqlsrv://admin_name:password(local)\SQLEXPRESS:/database_name --account-name=admin --account-mail=name@test.com --account-pass=Password1234 --site-mail="admin@company.com" --site-name="Site Name" install_configure_form.site_default_country=GB install_configure_form.date_default_timezone="Europe/London";
        string strExeCmd = @"C:\ProgramData\Drush\Drush.bat ";
        strExeCmd = strExeCmd + strArgs;
        string strLocation = @"C:\inetpub\application_name";

        session.Log("Starting Drush Configuration");
        session.Log("Command line is: " + strExeCmd + " " + strArgs);

        int exitCode;
        ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
        Process process;
        try
        {
            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + strExeCmd);
            processInfo.WorkingDirectory = strLocation;
            processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // *** Redirect the output ***
            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();

            // *** Read the streams ***
            string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            session.Log("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
            session.Log("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
            session.Log("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
            process.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            session.Log("Error: " + e);
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        session.Log("Drush Configuration completed successfully");
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

And as stated above, this always results in the "unable to decompress" error.

Has anyone ever used c# to run Site-Install in Drush?  Does anyone know why this might fail when executed in this way?

Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Drush Version: Drush-5.8-2012-12-10-Installer-v1.0.20